# how to add two query results as a single result in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to add two queries output as single result.

first query output is from "InvoiceDetail" table:

```
InvoiceID, POSCode, CQuantity, CPrice, TCost, AmountPaid

19327   07310000504 1   22.38   22.38   368.59
19326   07161030192 1   28.90   28.90   5402.69
19326   07013711044 2   12.53   25.06   5402.69
19327   07310000622 2   6.28    12.56   368.59
19326   07013721043 1   25.07   25.07   5402.69
19327   07310000626 2   6.28    12.56   368.59
19327   01230050268 2   37.15   74.30   368.59
19326   04210000910 2   9.84    19.68   5402.69
19327   01230050271 1   37.15   37.15   368.59
```

and my second query output is from "InvoiceCharge" table:

```
 InvoiceID  totalCharge
  19326 9.00
  19326 6.00
```

finally i want output like:

InvoiceID, POSCode, CQuantity, CPrice, TCost, AmountPaid, totalCharge

```
19327   07310000504 1   22.38   22.38   368.59   0.00
19326   07161030192 1   28.90   28.90   5402.69  15.00
19326   07013711044 2   12.53   25.06   5402.69  15.00
19327   07310000622 2   6.28    12.56   368.59    0.00
19326   07013721043 1   25.07   25.07   5402.69  15.00
19327   07310000626 2   6.28    12.56   368.59   0.00
19327   01230050268 2   37.15   74.30   368.59   0.00
19326   04210000910 2   9.84    19.68   5402.69  15.00
19327   01230050271 1   37.15   37.15   368.59    0.00
```

this is how i need..

here InvoiceID 19326 having charge(9.00+6.00)= 15.00
and InvoiceID 19327 having no charge, so no row found in InvoiceCharge table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please tried below query

```
select 
        InvoiceID, 
        POSCode, 
        CQuantity, 
        CPrice, 
        TCost, 
        AmountPaid, 
        (SELECT sum(totalCharge) FROM InvoiceCharge IC WHERE IC.InvoiceID = ID.InvoiceID) AS totalCharge 
from InvoiceDetail ID
```

Comment: Thanks it is woking fine for me

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select  InvoiceID, 
    POSCode, 
    CQuantity, 
    CPrice, 
    TCost, 
    AmountPaid,
    (case when a.charge is null then 0 else a.charge end)) as totalCharge
    from InvoiceDetail left join (SELECT sum(totalCharge) as charge , InvoiceCharge.InvoiceID FROM InvoiceCharge group by InvoiceCharge.InvoiceID) a on InvoiceCharge.InvoiceID = InvoiceDetail.InvoiceID
```